# How can I create a JSON string out of list of strings

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a JSON string like the following:

```
[{'street':'Address1'},
{'street':'Address2'},]
```

I just have a list of strings:

```
List<string> addresses = new List<string>()
addresses.Add("Address1");
addresses.Add("Address2");
```

I thought I could do something like this:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> toSend = addresses.Select(m => new KeyValuePair<string, string>() { "street", m });
```

and then use JsonConvert somehow.

Error:

> Error CS1922  Cannot initialize type 'KeyValuePair'
>   with a collection initializer because it does not implement
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create anonymous type list from string array and then convert to JSON
like below

```
List<string> addresses = new List<string>()
addresses.Add("Address1");
addresses.Add("Address2");

var jsonString= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(addresses.Select(w=> new { street = w }));
```

Note : You need to include

```
using Newtonsoft.Json; 
using System.Linq;
```

**Output will be like below**

[image]